# SQL Server remove special character from table

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have table in SQL Server with a column `Team`, but when inserting data through BCP, some special character are on the first line:

```
 TEAM   
 ∩╗┐1.Insta Acq
```

I tried with the code shown here, but with no success. I copied the special symbol and paste it in the replace function as

```
 REPLACE(COLUMN NAME,'∩╗┐1.Insta Acq', '1.Insta Acq' )
```

Datatypes:

```
 COLUMN_NAME    DATA_TYPE   TYPE_NAME
 -------------------------------------
 TEAM           -9          nvarchar
 SOURCE         12          varchar
 STAGE          12          varchar
 TARGET OCT'22  4           int
```

Sample data in the table:

```
 TEAM           SOURCE   STAGE                      TARGET OCT'22
------------------------------------------------------------------
 ∩╗┐1.Insta Acq Website  TB Active / TB Inactive    9000
 1.Insta Acq    Website  No Offer                   3500
```

Comment: nvarchar DATATYPE...

Comment: @MitchWheat ADDED BOTH SAMPLE DATA AND DATATYPE

Comment: Since it's an `NVARCHAR` column - you **must use** the `N` prefix in the `REPLACE` call: `REPLACE(COLUMN NAME, N'∩╗┐1.Insta Acq',  N'1.Insta Acq')` to make it clear these are **Unicode** string literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with "special" characters that are probably Unicode, you **must use** the `N` prefix in your `REPLACE` call to indicate that these are **Unicode** string literals you're working with.

Try this:

```
REPLACE(COLUMN NAME, N'∩╗┐1.Insta Acq', N'1.Insta Acq')
```